# Send data from a sheet object to a connector

Tags: qlikview

I know that using a data pipe with QVX, QlikView can request data from a connector:
[image]
But I was wondering is whether we can send the data currently in one sheet object such as a table object or a multibox object back to a connector. Because as can be seen from the image above the data pipe can only stream from the custom connector to QlikView and not the other way round.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot give you a 100% definitive answer, but I would say no for the following reason:

QVXs are used via a QlikView load script to obtain data from a custom data source, and as such are only able to be executed when the script is executed on a reload. QVXs cannot be executed outside of a load script, and furthermore, a load script does not and cannot access document objects such as charts or dimension filters so as a result, even if you could pass data back, you could not feed it from a document object.